# Test TLS TCP Endpoint

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, telnet

I have TCP endpoint for a Service running with `TLS` (Self-Signed) Certificate. To test this endpoint I use `openssl s_client -connect service.domain.com:5050` which prints `CONNECTED(00000006)` nothing else.

I have cert & key for the self-signed certificate I am using for this endpoint. How can I use the key with `openssl` command above ?

If this is not possible with `openssl`, what other way I can test this ?

Comment: You _can_ tell `s_client` to trust a server's selfsigned cert with `-CAfile` and/or `-CApath`; see the man page. But you don't need to; `s_client` is designed as a test/debug tool and even if the server cert isn't trusted `s_client` will continue with a warning (which is fairly subtle and easily missed). You appear to be getting no protocol response at all from the server. Try `s_client ... -debug` to see in much more detail what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man s_client` reveals:

```
   -cert certname
       The certificate to use, if one is requested by the server. The default is not to use a certificate.

   -key keyfile
       The private key to use. If not specified then the certificate file will be used.
```

Look also at `-keyform` and `-certform` if necessary.

Also, nowadays, always using `-servername` (to enable SNI) makes sense.

Comment: Like this ? `openssl s_client -cert ~/test/service_domain_com.crt -key ~/test/service_domain_com.key -servername service.domain.com:5050`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problem yesterday. That endpoint was a Microsoft IIS 8.0 server, which wasn't able to talk modern TLS 1.2 and 1.3, and `s_client` was stopping exactly after CONNECTED(...). Other server only didn't support TLS 1.3. So, in my case, `-tls1` or `-tls1_1` key of the `s_client` helped.